# Syntax? Set string variable to string value when element is clicked

Tags: jquery, string, switch-statement, attr

```
$('#Colors span').live('click', function(){
    var layerFind = "BACK";

    if ($(this).hasClass('.CI_W')) {
        layerFind = "WHITE";
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('.CI_U')) {
        layerFind = "BLUE";
    } else {
        layerFind = "BASE";
    }       

    $("#Base").attr("src", 'Layers/' + layerFind + '.png');
});
```

I have spans that are icons that represent colors. When a user clicks the icon, the string variable layerFind changes to the appropriate color. This string is then used as the src for an image file. Currently it works for the BASE string value, that is the default when i load the page, but it doesn't respond to the span clicks.

I'm wondering if a switch statement makes more sense. Later on i will need this script to be able to combine the colors clicked. For example, if i click the white icon and the black icon, the string becomes WB, an abbreviation, and the image file with that name is a gray image. If i click 3 or more, then it uses a secondary default, for example, RAINBOW or something.

Comment: Could you post more information, the html involved.  Ideally a working example perhaps a jsfiddle.  I see no reason why this would not work.

Answer (score 1):

dude, your trouble is simple, just remove de $ in the variables inside the ifs